# LNK2019 unresolved symbol compiling LuaJava with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, lnk2019, luajava

I am working with visual studio 2012 to compile LuaJava.  The problem I am having is when I call the linker.  The line that calls the linker in the makefile is:

```
 link  /dll /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64" 
       /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64" 
       /out:luajava-1.1.dll src\c\luajava.obj 
       "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lib\lua5.1.lib" /VERBOSE
```

This seems to almost be linking everything successfully, until it gets to the Lua library.

The linker outputs the following when I try to make the project:

```
...//linking of other libraries
Finished searching libraries

Unused libraries:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lib\lua5.1.lib
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64\OLDNAMES.lib

luajava.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lua_close referenced in function Java_org_keplerproject_luajava_LuaState__1close
luajava.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lua_newthread referenced in function Java_org_keplerproject_luajava_LuaState__1newthread
luajava.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lua_gettop referenced in function Java_org_keplerproject_luajava_LuaState__1getTop
...//lots of these errors 
luajava-1.1.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 88 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

I'm confused as to why it says that the Lua library is unused, and then complains when it can't find the Lua library functions.

Comment: Are you trying to link a 32bit library to a 64 bit application? That will not work.

Comment: Hmm... That's a good point. I used Lua for Windows to install Lua, and I think it was a 32 bit copy, so the Lua library is likely 32 bit.  I'll check further into this and get back to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not link a 32 bit library to your 64 bit application. After some searces I do not believe LuaJava has a x64 download so to use this you must change your application to 32 bit.

Edit: 
A second method would be to recomile LuaJava as a 64 bit dll. Here is a very recent post about that: [LuaJava compile error "Unresolved external symbol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728418/luajava-compile-error-unresolved-external-symbol)